# C++ error : Sleep was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, boost

I am using C++ in Ubuntu with codeBlocks, boost 1.46 in GCC 4.7 [ yield_k.hpp ]

I get this compile time error:

```
error : Sleep was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
  cout << "nitrate";
  cout << flush;
  sleep(1000);
  cout << "firtilizers";
  return 0;
}
```

How do I resolve this error?  I want the program to hang for 1 second.

Comment: You have to write `#include <unistd.h>`, with the angled brackets.

Comment: @KerrekSB shouldn't he get an error on the #include line if those were missing?

Comment: @daramarak, The only sure thing is "nothing worked". There could have been an error on both lines. Not exactly sure how boost plays into this either. It's just a mention, not a boost-related question.

Comment: 1. Shouldn't `sleep()` be with a lowercase `s`? 2. I guess the `expected initialized before 'sleep'` probably means that you forgot a semicolon in one of the lines before `sleep()`...

Comment: I included #include <unistd.h> dint work, and I also changed Sleep() to sleep()

Comment: error definition:
/home/mypc/Down/boost_1_48_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp:88:18: error: ‘Sleep’ was not declared in this scope
P.S. Boost 1.48 is in use

Comment: @EitanT suggestion sounds plausible. But we can only guess without any code.

Comment: sleep(), with a lower case, is defined in <unistd.h>, see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sleep.html
Now, my guess is that something is getting confused in the headers, so  I start from scratch and see what interrupts compilation..

Comment: Digital Da, I did try your suggestion , but still does not work.

Comment: I get an error:expected initializer before 'sleep' extern "C" void __stdcall sleep( unsigned long ms );

Comment: In my case  including `#include <unistd.h>` works with `s` in lowercase.

Comment: I was getting this error even after adding `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Sleep` is a Windows function.

For Unix, look into using `nanosleep` (POSIX) or `usleep` (BSD; deprecated).

A `nanosleep` example:

```
void my_sleep(unsigned msec) {
    struct timespec req, rem;
    int err;
    req.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
    req.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * 1000000;
    while ((req.tv_sec != 0) || (req.tv_nsec != 0)) {
        if (nanosleep(&req, &rem) == 0)
            break;
        err = errno;
        // Interrupted; continue
        if (err == EINTR) {
            req.tv_sec = rem.tv_sec;
            req.tv_nsec = rem.tv_nsec;
        }
        // Unhandleable error (EFAULT (bad pointer), EINVAL (bad timeval in tv_nsec), or ENOSYS (function not supported))
        break;
    }
}
```

You will need `<time.h>` and `<errno.h>`, available in C++ as `<ctime>` and `<cerrno>`.

`usleep` is simpler to use (just multiply by 1000, so make it an inline function). However, it's impossible to guarantee that that sleeping will occur for a given amount of time, it's deprecated, and you need to `extern "C" { }`-include `<unistd.h>`.

A third choice is to use `select` and `struct timeval`, as seen in http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/ntdll/sync.c#l1204 (this is how wine emulates `Sleep`, which itself is just a wrapper for `SleepEx`).

**Note**: `sleep` (lowercase 's'), whose declaration is in `<unistd.h>`, is *not* an acceptable substitute, since its granularity is seconds, coarser than that of Windows' `Sleep` (uppercase 's'), which has a granularity of milliseconds.

Regarding your second error, `___XXXcall` is a MSVC++-specific token (as are `__dllXXX`, `__naked`, `__inline`, etc.). If you *really* need stdcall, use `__attribute__((stdcall))` or similar to emulate it in gcc.

**Note**: unless your compile target is a Windows binary *and* you're using Win32 APIs, use of or a requirement for `stdcall` is A Bad Sign™.

Comment: Thanks moshbear, I fixed it by changing 'Sleep' to 'sleep' and since I needed to use stdcall, is used your solution __attribute__((stdcall)). Thanks

Comment: `sleep` does seconds, not milliseconds; you'd be better off writing a select loop as is done in wine (`select` is also supported by Winsock) or copy pasting the my_sleep. `nanosleep` is a bit more elegant than `select`, IMO. Don't forget the `#ifndef _WINDOWS` or equivalent.

Comment: @timothy: You shouldn't need `__attribute__((stdcall))` to call POSIX functions.

Comment: That winehq source code, the line number might be out of date, try this:

Answer (score 17):

### How to use usleep in a C++ program on linux:

Put this in a file called `s.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
  cout << "nitrate";
  cout << flush;
  usleep(1000000);
  cout << "firtilizers";
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it and run it:

```
el@defiant ~/foo4/40_usleep $ g++ -o s s.cpp
el@defiant ~/foo4/40_usleep $ ./s
nitratefirtilizers
```

It printed 'nitrate', waited 1 second, then printed 'firtilizers'

Comment: `#include <unistd.h>` fixed the problems I was having, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const long a=1000000;
    long j;
    cin >> j;
    usleep(a*j);
    puts("exit");
}
```

use `usleep()` Insted of sleep and **Don't forget to Include `unistd.h`** (Not `cunistd`)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helped to write **S**leep and NOT **s**leep - very strange, but worked!

Comment: What environment are you on? windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <tread>


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{       
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}
```